# Java thread and synchronizedlist

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I've been learning java and trying out threading and using synchronizedlist.

```
package Multithreading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>(10));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        list.add(0);
    }
    Thread a = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread b = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread c = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread d = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread e = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread f = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread g = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    Thread h = new Thread(new CardPicker(list));
    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
    d.start();
    e.start();
    f.start();
    g.start();
    h.start();
    int startTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    while((int) System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime<10000){

    }
    System.out.println(list.toString());

}
}

package Multithreading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class CardPicker implements Runnable{

List<Integer> list;
public CardPicker(List<Integer> list2){
    this.list = list2;
}

@Override
    public void run() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int hold = rnd.nextInt(10);
    while(true){
        list.set(hold, list.get(hold)+1);
    }
}

}
```

Somehow the output gives me something like:

[13289041, 13038238, 0, 13427372, 10113077, 13023511, 15722188, 0, 12728814, 0]

[12532173, 0, 0, 12254025, 12406768, 16276566, 12638446, 16651720, 0, 0]

Where these 0s come from? Thanks

Comment: Thread are running in an infinite loop. Second use `join` if you want to output `main` method in the end .

Comment: But the thread is running a while(true) loop - doesn't join wait for the thread to terminate itself? Which is in this case, until an outofmemoryexception?

Comment: Even though you use a synchronized list, your code is **not thread-safe** the `get` and `set` can interleave.

Answer (score 2):

> Where these 0s come from?

First of all you have added 10 items in list having zero value.

At below lines you are replacing the value at a random index.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int hold = rnd.nextInt(10);
while(true){
    list.set(hold, list.get(hold)+1);
}
```

**You have 8 threads and 10 values in the list. Now for each thread a random number is generated just for single time it means in extreme case where a different random number is generated for each thread still you have 2 indexes in the list that is not replaced.**

You can try it again after moving below line in `while` loop but still its not 100% sure that all the indexes are replaced. Its depends on the behavior of `Random`.

```
int hold = rnd.nextInt(10);
```

Fore more info have a look at [Random#nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29).

Comment: What are some of the indexes not replaced?